# Error zip argument #1 must support iteration

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

When I try to execute this code

```
g = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
zip(*g)
```

I get the following error

> zip argument #1 must support iteration

I am trying to convert row into column vector

I even tried `map(list, zip(*gate))` still I get the same error

Please help

Comment: Well did you try `zip(g)`?

Comment: @vaultah thanks...it worked

Comment: The reason he wrote this is that there are other answers by knowledgeable python folks that _do_ use `zip(*g)` .  E.g. here https://stackoverflow.com/a/43437266/1056563

Answer (score 6):

With `zip(*g)` syntax, you are doing list unpacking. The following code:

```
g = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
zip(*g)
```

Is equivalent to:

```
zip(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```

Since *g* list contains `int` values (but not iterable collection) you get an error.

*notice: the [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html?highlight=zip#zip) function can have a variable list of parameters*.

So, to fix your problem you need to write:

```
zip(g)
```

Remember that, in Python 3, *zip* return a generator. To get a list you need to use the `list` function:

```
>>> list(zip([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]))
[(1,), (2,), (3,), (4,), (5,), (6,)]
```

Comment: Thx for the answer: it's not your fault that python makes simple things unnecessarily hard / brittle.